# Cannot be root on Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, vmware

I'm currently trying to develop an application for Android devices on an Android Emulator. I installed Android 4.3 on a VMWare Workstation, on a Windows 10 OS.

I want to test the app I'm developping on the Android emulator, so I have to create a bridge connection between my phyisical computer where I develop the aps, and the emulator, where I can test it. But when I try to create this bridge, **I have to change settings and to be root of the emulator**. When I try to do a 'su' command, I have the following error :

```
'su : uid 10000 not allowed to su'
```

I tried to follow this tutorial to give me the root acces of the emulator, but it didn't worked for me. The best answer is to execute this commands :

```
adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system  
adb push su /system/xbin/su  
adb shell chmod 06755 /system  
adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
```

[How to get root access on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator)

More over, When I did the installation of the Android Emulator, I've done the installation specifying the read-write option.

It is not working for me, because when I try the first row, I obtain this message :

```
ADB error : 'device not found'
```

Such as it is described in this link :
[How to fix: Error device not found with ADB.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705089/how-to-fix-error-device-not-found-with-adb-exe)

But the answer exists for a phone, and not for an emulator. Do you know how to fix it ? How can I be root, and how can I found the 'device not found' ?

[Here are the different parameters of the VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7V7y.png)

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot get adb to work with your emulator?

Comment: Yes, when I try to run the commands on this emulator, The command says `ADB error : device not found` and i'm not able to be root on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

su stands for super users which is available only on rooted device. it is more like using android application with administrator privilege.Try using BLuestacks rooted version.

Comment: Thank you for the BlueStacks software, I will try it. Is it possible to run my own app on my desktop ?

Comment: BlueStacks is again an Android Simulator and it yes you can use android apps on Bluestacks, even whatsapp