# How to connect and configure android studio on real time android device (Smartphones etc.)?

Tags: android, android-studio, real-time, smartphone, android-devicetoken

I have read a lot of blogs and saw many videos but no one explain how to run a Hello world App on a smartphone. Can somebody please help me in running a simple hello world program on android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this post: http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/connect-configure-app-on-real-android-device-and-run-hello-world-program-with-android-studio/

Here everything is explained from how to connect and configure android studio with android real time device (in your case Smartphone) and then run Hello World App. I hope it will resolve your query. All the Best. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Install `usb_drivers` in machine and turn `Developer options` in device and you can run android application into device directly.

- **Enable `Developer Options`**

Goto Settings -> Developer Options -> turn it on also turn on `USB Debugging`

- **Install `usb_drivers` in machine**

You can find the `inf` file of `usb_drivers` in sdk -> extras -> google -> usb_driver folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following in your smartPhone.

1. Go to Settings -> About Device -> You will see Build Number -> You need to tap on Build number 7 times. Once you do this, you will get a message "You are a developer now".
2. Now once you get back to Settings -> You will see "Developer Options" enabled and this will appear one row up above "About Device".
3. In developer options -> Turn on USB debugging - This is to ensure when we connect our phone or device USB connection can enable debugging. Turn developer option ON.
4. In Settings -> Security -> Device Administration -> Enable "Allow Installation of apps from Unknown Sources". This is to ensure that apk file from your PC can be installed and run.
5. Once you complete all these steps, your device is now ready to be a development device.

Drivers:

In case if you have not downloaded the USB drivers for your device already [ this is to ensure your device is visible as you connect via USB], please do the same from the device manufacturer site. Most of the devices will download this automatically, but a few devices we need to do this ourselves.

Once these things are done, now when you click on Run in Android Studio on your "hello world" project, you should see YOUR DEVICE also in the list.

in case if you still face issues, please follow the instructions mentioned here, [How to fix: Error device not found with ADB.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705089/how-to-fix-error-device-not-found-with-adb-exe)

Hope this helps. All the best!